# What is the norm on the functional space used in defining the generator of a homogeneous Markov process?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_semigroup#Infinitesimal_generator):

> Given a strongly continuous semigroup $T : \mathbb{R}_+ \to L(B)$ on a Banach space $B$, its infinitesimal generator $A$ of a strongly continuous semigroup $T$ is defined as a mapping $B \to B$ as
>   $$
>     A\,x = \lim_{t\downarrow0} \frac1t\,(T(t)- I)\,x , \forall x \in B
> $$
>   whenever the limit exists wrt the norm on the Banach space $B$.

For a homogeneous Markov process $X_t, t \geq 0$ with state space $\mathbb R^n$, we can define a Banach space $B$ as the set of some measurable functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ equipped with some norm (?), and a semigroup $T : \mathbb{R}_+ \to L(B)$ as 
$$
[[T(t)](f)](x) := \mathbf{E}^{x} [f(X_{t})], \forall f \in B, \forall x \in \mathbb R^n
$$

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_%28stochastic_processes%29)

> The infinitesimal generator of the process $X$ is the operator $A$, which is defined to act on suitable functions $f : \mathbb R^n → \mathbb R$ by
>   $$
>     A f (x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbf{E}^{x} [f(X_{t})] - f(x)}{t}, \forall x \in \mathbb R^n $$

Compared to the generator for a general semigroup, we can try to rewrite the definition of $A$ as
$$
    A f  = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{ F(t,f) - f}{t},  $$
where $F(t,f)(x) := \mathbf{E}^{x} [f(X_{t})]$.
Now I was wondering what is the norm on $B$, the set of some measurable functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, wrt which the above limit is taken?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

In the most general definition, you can take $T_t:B\to B$ to be defined by

$$(T_tf)(x) = E^xf(X_t),$$

where $B$ is the space of all bounded and Borel measurable mappings from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the uniform norm. The uniform norm is almost invariably used, as this makes the space complete. In general, however, this space is much too large, and the generator will only exist on a much smaller set. The most useful theory is obtained by considering the restriction of $T_t$ to $C_0(\mathbb{R}^p)$, the subspace of $B$ of continuous mappings which vanish at infinity. When $T_t$ maps $C_0(\mathbb{R}^p)$ into itself and $t\mapsto T_tf$ is continuous at zero for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^p)$ the semigroup is said to be Feller. In this case, the generator exists on a dense subspace of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^p)$.

For more on this, see "Markov processes" by Ethier & Kurtz, or "Functional analysis for Probability and Stochastic Processes" by Bobrowski.